# Adjusting Newton's laws with relativity concepts

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, special-relativity, forces, acceleration, inertial-frames

I break my question into three parts, with increasing "guessing status". Please tell me which of them (is any) is correct.

- Suppose I am an observer in an inertial reference frame, away from all other masses influence. When relativistic velocities are implied, do Newton's laws of motion still hold if I use the concept of relativistic mass (that is, introducing the gamma factor within the momentum)?
- Now suppose I am an observer in a non inertial reference frame (submit to a force, for example electromagnetic force), but still away from all other masses influence. When relativistic velocities are implied, do Newton's laws of motion still hold if I use the concept of relativistic mass AND introduce a fictitious force "in the classic way" (depending on my state of motion with respect to an inertial reference frame)?
- Final step. Now suppose I am in a non inertial reference frame (submit to a force) AND under the influence of other masses. When relativistic velocities are implied, do Newton's laws of motion still hold if I use the concept of relativistic mass AND introduce a fictitious force in the classic way AND use Newton's law of gravitation?

Comment: For your first point, are you asking does ${\bf F} = \gamma m_0 {\bf a}$?

Comment: Yes indeed, without any reference to the "time component" of the Force Vector

Comment: Note that "relativistic mass" is direction dependent.

Comment: @Poutnik yes I know. I should not be a problem since this is a vectorial equation (I just have to take care when I project it on the spatial axes)

Comment: You last part is a really horrible mix of half-theories that just don't fit together.  You would be far better served to just learn special and general relativity.

Comment: @m4r35n357 ok. What abuot the previous parts?

Comment: Slightly less bad, but still mixed up.  I still advise just learning SR.  Why avoid it?

Comment: @m4r35n357 I did learn the basis of both SR and GR. However, it is a very different approach with respect to Newton's, when it comes to the resolution of mechanical problems. I don't find it intuitive at all. That's why I am trying to understang if I can still use Newton's approach with the above adjustment, though it is probably less elegant than using Einstein's theory

Comment: That's probably beacause I am an engineer and not a physicist... I prefer practicality rather than elegance

Comment: Well, talking of practicality, the most practical way to obtain relativistically correct results is to use relativity. The most practical way of thinking about relativistc phenomenon is thinking about them with relativity in mind.